# child node in MBR (R-Tree Implementation)

Tags: database, indexing, r-tree

I am new to R-Tree concept. Sorry If I ask a very basic question related to Rtree. I have read a few literature on R-Tree to get the basic concept of R-Tree. However, I could not understand the clustering or grouping steps in MBR. What's bothering me is:

How many points or object could fit in each MBR? i could see that the number of object stored in each MBR is varies. So is there any condition or procedure or formula or anything to determine how many objects will be stored in each MBR?

Thanks for your help! Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the R-tree publication, or a book on index structures.

You fix a page size (because the R-tree is a disk-oriented data structure, this should be something such as e.g. 8kb).

If a page gets too empty, it will be removed. If a page is too full, it will be split.
Just like with pretty much any other page-based tree, actually (e.g. B-tree).